# How can I change the field of an object by specifying its path?

Tags: c#

Is it really possible to specify an array of "paths" to the fields in advance in order to change them inside the object later?
Without duplicating the Do() call

```cs
class Item
{
    public int Value1 { get; set; }
    public int Value2 { get; set; }
    public int Value3 { get; set; }
    public int Value4 { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
var targetItem = new Item();
var common1 = new Item();
var common2 = new Item();

var functions = new List<Func<Item, int>>
            {
                i => i.Value1,
                i => i.Value2,
                i => i.Value3,
                i => i.Value4
            };

foreach(var func in functions)
{
    func(targetItem) = Do(func); //something
}

int Do(Func<Item, int> func)
{
    //super hard logic
    return func(common1) + func(common2);
}
```

this example outputs

> func(targetItem) = Do(func); ->
> CS0131  The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer

```cs
targetItem.Value1 = Do(i => i.Value1);
targetItem.Value2 = Do(i => i.Value2);
targetItem.Value3 = Do(i => i.Value3);
targetItem.Value4 = Do(i => i.Value4);
```

I can certainly do this, but it's not very nice :)

Thanks

Comment: What you're talking about doing is _possible_ using reflection, but I would recommend taking a step back and thinking about whether your model really makes sense. Why have `Value1`, `Value2`, etc., instead of just a list of `Values`?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior This object is for example. The values must be identified by name. In fact, there are many other objects inside and the path to the final values is something like item.Object1.Object 4.SomeValue

Comment: There are several ways one might solve the kind of problem you're describing. It might make sense to use reflection to set the property values, or have the properties be pass-throughs to an underlying dictionary, or to turn your whole object into a JsonObject and use JPaths. The right approach here will depend on the _why_ behind your question. You have a big list of properties, some of them several objects deep, which you need to update based on the same property/path values in a different object: what is it that ties those property values together, conceptually, in your business model?